# What thing I can get from iPhone when you are developer

Tags: iphone

I want develop application for read user information on iPhone

1. IP Address/ Wi-Fi Address
2. Network
3. Version
4. Serial Number
5. Latitude (map)
6. Longitude (map)

what kind of these thing I can read or it can't, please suggest me in your opinion.
Thanks.

Comment: These questions are very answerable with your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve all of those.